# Order filenames by number of appereances of given character?

Tags: bash, filenames

I want to output a list of file names in a directory, where the list should be ordered descending by the number of appeareances of a given character in each file name. How can I do this with bash?

Comment: @anishsane I have a solution written in Mathematica. Will that help?

Comment: What does your input names look like? Does it have spaces or other special characters in names? Is the repeated character consistently on one side of the name (e.g. abb.txt, aab.txt aaa.txt) or is split (e.g. aba.txt)?

Comment: Maybe, but not if you don't share it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let say you want to sort by occurences of "a" in file names:

```
for i in *; do; echo "`grep -o "a" <<< "$i" | wc -l` $i"; done | sort -r
```

**Result**

```
$ ls
carla
elaine
guybrush
herman
largo
leamon-head
lechuck
max
meathook
ozzie
sam
stan
voodoo

$ for i in *; do; echo "`grep -o "a" <<< "$i" | wc -l` $i"; done | sort -r
2 leamon-head
2 carla
1 stan
1 sam
1 meathook
1 max
1 largo
1 herman
1 elaine
0 voodoo
0 ozzie
0 lechuck
0 guybrush
```